# Scaling tile grid

Tags: actionscript-3, matrix, grid, scaling, tile

I'm working on my own tile bliting engine, this one is using hexagonal tiles - but I think it doesn't differ much from regular tiles.

I have huge x,y array of tiles and they have their x,y coordinates for rendering on canvas, I iterate only the ones that should be visible on canvas in current camera position.

So I'm stuck with scaling and cant resolve this on my own.
Here is my code for drawing tiles on canvas:

```
public function draw():Void{
    clearCanvas(); //Clear canvas (bitmapData)
            var _m:Matrix;
            iterateTiles(function(_tile:HexTile):Void{ // loop every tile that is visible on screen
                _m = new Matrix();
                _m.translate(_tile.x + cameraPoint.x,_tile.y  + cameraPoint.y);//Get pre calculated tile x,y and add camera x,y
                _m.scale(matrixScale, matrixScale);
                drawToCanvas(_tile,_m);//Send to draw tile on canvas using Matrix
            },true);
        }
```

This works nice and fast but only problem is it scales tiles from left top corner (like regular scale would work)

[Before scale](http://img.lejup.lv/images/lejupyfuzgeq1357649628.png)

---

[After scale](http://img.lejup.lv/images/lejupjiyndic1357649628.png)

> **My question is how to transform tiles to always scale from center. So if tile 10:10 is in center of screen before scaling, then it should
>   stay there after scaling.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I misunderstood the question, but I think I've got it now:

```
// Scale the distance from the original point to the center of the canvas
var xDistance:Number = ((_tile.x + cameraPoint.x) - xCenter) * matrixScale;
var yDistance:Number = ((_tile.y + cameraPoint.y) - yCenter) * matrixScale;

// Add the distances to the center of the canvas. This is where you want the tile 
// to appear.
var x:Number = xCenter + xDistance;
var y:Number = yCenter + yDistance;

// Because the coordinate is going to be scaled, you need to increase it first.
x = (1 / matrixScale) * x;
y = (1 / matrixScale) * y;

_m.translate(x, y);
```

I have not tested this, I've just drawn it out on graph paper. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Yes, but this just changes the position of every tile by half of width and height. How does this help with scaling ?

Comment: By shifting the tiles position left/up by half the scaled width/height, the center of each tile will always be at _tile.x, _tile.y, even when the tile is scaled. Is that what you are aiming for, or did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: It's something different. I need all the tiles to scale together and offset together to keep 10:10 (or whatever tile is in center of canvas at the time) in center after scaling. 
I'm only scaling down, so keep 10:10 in center that would involve offsetting it by some +x +y value, I think this value should be related to dimensions of "canvas" and scale

Comment: He's not worried about individual tiles, but all the tiles at once so that the scaling doesn't move them up and to the left.  You'll need to calculate the offset x,y that occurs with the scaling.  For example, if tile 10,10 moves -50 x and -50 y after the scale, figure out a formula that handles this for all scales and add it to the drawing function. The problem with the code is that the tiles change in quantity on the screen, so you might have to rethink how you approach rendering them.

Comment: Please see my revised answer above.